# Netty: Safe SSL implementation

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, netty

I basically tried to implement Netty's build in SSLHandler. I had no problems until i implemented the Client-Side SSL.
I tried everything out any neither of all tries actually checked an incoming certificate of a Server. I could basically connect me to invalid SSL Servers.

I only saw codes like these on the internet:

```
pipeline.addLast("ssl", SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build().newHandler(channel.alloc(), UserConnection.SERVER_API_DOMAIN, UserConnection.SERVER_CONNECTION_PORT));
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why are you setting `.trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)`? That sounds like it's exactly what you don't want. I don't know netty's SslContextBuilder but I'd hope it'd use a default validating trust manager if you leave that bit out.

Comment: I am not using that. Its basically the stuff i found in the internet. I can literally not find any thing else.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in `.trustManager(null)` , you get the system default which should check certificates based on the default root certs you have on your system.

To quote docs https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslContextBuilder.html#trustManager-java.lang.Iterable-
:

> Trusted certificates for verifying the remote endpoint's certificate, null uses the system default

Of course, you could also leave out the `.trustManager(...)` call altogether, since the default is `null`

Comment: pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager((X509Certificate) null).build().newEngine(channel.alloc(), SERVER_API_DOMAIN, SERVER_CONNECTION_PORT)));

Error Server: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
Error Client:  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine Problem

It throws an error